# Trigger Google GeoChart tooltip outside of map

Tags: google-visualization

I'm looking to show a country's tooltip from outside of the geochart.  I've searched through the API, but I'm not seeing the method for doing so.

```
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['geochart'] });

google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Country","Count"],
        ["Mexico",600],
        ["Canada",400]
    ]);

    new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map')).draw(data);
});
</script>

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Is there a way to trigger the map tooltips when hovering over the links above?</p>
```

[Here's a very basic fiddle to start with](http://jsfiddle.net/fWMJS/)

Comment: You cannot trigger the tooltips by any means other than hovering the mouse over the points on the map.

Comment: Well that's a bummer.

Comment: I was searching for the same feature. Bummer x 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this overriding styling for Google Chart Tooltips defined by:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/core/tooltip.css

Use for example:

```
<style>
.google-visualization-tooltip {
    border: dashed 1px !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 30px !important;
    right: 250px !important;
    margin: 10px 0 0 400px !important;
}
</style>
```

Tooltip will be floating on the right side of chart.

Comment: While you are technically correct, I should have chosen a different word from "outside".  What I meant was to trigger the tooltip externally from the map.  Thanks tho!  :D